# apt upgrade failing release file not found

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have inherited an AWS EC2 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I am trying to register it on livepatch and esm-infra. Livepatch works, but i can't enable esm-infra, nor can i run a `apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial InRelease
Ign:5 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial Release
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Hit:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Hit:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Err:6 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:7 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://deb.goaccess.io xenial/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://deb.goaccess.io xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.goaccess.io/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have updated /etc/resolv.conf to add 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4, no luck.
Below is `/etc/apt/sources.list` i don't see anything out of the ordinary.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Comment: This is because 16.04 was released in 2016 with 5 years of standard support, so it no longer gets community support including updates. We also no longer support questions about this version on Ask Ubuntu. You can sign up for ESM. It is free for personal use and the basic subscription allows access to security and other "critical" updates. It's strongly recommended that you upgrade or install a supported release.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i understand 16.04 LTS is beyond standard support and the point of my question was that it was failing to enable esm-infra because it couldn't make it through an apt-get update. Regardless, i found that this box had goaccess installed on it and the file `goaccess.list` was found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which overruled the repos and causing the file not found error. Anyway, uninstalling goaccess solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove goaccess
```

I'll leave this here just in case someone else stumbles on this question, that was the solution. Cheers.

EDIT: goaccess, not geoaccess. lol.

Comment: Kudos for reading your apt output. Most apt questions are indeed solved that way.